# Powershell - I want to reuse constants in param section

Tags: powershell, parameters, code-reuse

I have quite a few constants that are common to a few scripts. 
I thought of writing a common section, and dot source it in my script.
I also want to use these constants to init defaults for parameters using a "param" section.
But the param section should be the first non-comment line in the script, so I can't dot source before it.
Any suggestions on how to do it "correctly"?
Of course I can give default values on a "Regular" code after the "params" section...
Something like if $param is empty, set $param = CONST...

Example:
ConstantsFile.ps1

```
Set-Variable COMMON_CONST_num -option Constant -value 100
Set-Variable COMMON_CONST_path -option Constant -value "C:\Example\Example"
```

Script:

```
. .\ConstantsFile.ps1

param 
( 
    [string]$targetPath = "$COMMON_CONST_path"
    [string]$number = "$COMMON_CONST_num"
)
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Why not make your scripts into a module?

You can then make each script into a function, dot-source your standard variables at the top of the module (or dispense with that idea and just include them in the module) and set all the default variable values in each function's param section:

```
<#
My-Module.psm1
#>

#Set my module variables
Set-Variable COMMON_CONST_num -option Constant -value 100
Set-Variable COMMON_CONST_path -option Constant -value "C:\Example\Example"

#Dot-Source my common variables
. .\ConstantsFile.ps1

function My-function1
{
    param 
    ( 
        [string]$Function1targetPath = "$COMMON_CONST_path",
        [string]$Function1number = "$COMMON_CONST_num"
    )

    #Do Stuff
}

function My-function2
{
    param 
    ( 
        [string]$Function2targetPath = "$COMMON_CONST_path",
        [string]$Function2number = "$COMMON_CONST_num"
    )

    #Do Stuff
}
```

You will probably find that this approach allows you to create some common functions for the scripts too.

Comment: Thanks, This is an interesting approach, even though my current scripts are quite long, with functions of their own. But it worth thinking, and keeping this in mind for new scripts.

Comment: So you could move the bits of the script which use these common variables to a supporting module as functions, keeping the logic in the main script. Then load the module at the start of the script and call the functions as you need, passing parameters to override the default variables if you need to.